# Can't get mesh to follow path nurb

Tags: constraints

[Video example of the issue on a fresh scene](https://www.veed.io/view/9a4a510b-b19c-450e-ac4a-fcd3e473392f?sharingWidget=true&panel=)

SOLUTION: When you create a nurbs path and the use the pencil tool to draw it, the original nurbs path still remains and acts as the main path for the constraint. After deleting said path, the mesh starts to follow the newly drawn nurbs path

I'm trying to get a mesh to follow a nurbsPath with the follow path constraint but i can't get it working at all. While it gets constrained to the position of the nurbsPath, It only slides to the side without following the path.

All transforms are zero-d and are at the center of the scene, tried checking most settings in the constrain (fixed position)

I had it work just previously, i tried comparing the settings between the two but to no avail.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello, the video doesn't seem to work, please share your file here (only keep the useful elements): https://blend-exchange.com/